# Close Vote Guidance

Tags: discussion, review-audits, close-reasons, disputed-review-audits

The review audit system has admonished me to leave the following question open.

[Understand structured binding in C++17 by analogy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49795131/understand-structured-binding-in-c17-by-analogy)

I am not a C++ programmer, but the actual question seems to be,

> what are the key points this analogy failed to catch?

Does it matter how good the analogy is in this case? I would have voted to close this question as too broad. I think an argument could also be made for the opinion-based close reason.

Why is this a good audit?

Comment: One thing I have noticed doing endless close vote reviews is that almost any question discussing the finer points of C++ is going to be highly upvoted and an audit.

Comment: That's an interesting observation, but what should I take away from it as a reviewer? Never vote to close C++ questions?

Comment: It doesn't really look that broad to me because it's talking about a specific example. But surely with the huge close vote queue you could just concentrate on languages you know by filtering by tags?

Comment: It is the kind of constructed audit that tests if reviewers pay attention to the actual Q+A.  Always starts out with a highly upvoted post, if you then try to whack it then it assumes the "look" phrase in the audit completion message is relevant.

Comment: @PeterJ, I had thought that subjectivity is language agnostic; so I'm keen to know what feature in this case makes an otherwise open-ended question less broad.

Answer (score 3):

The question is fine. It is neither too broad nor primarily opinion-based. Its scope (a specific language feature) is entirely reasonable. The analogy is merely the vehicle the OP chose to present their current understanding of the matter, and so the "what are the key points this analogy failed to catch?" phrasing doesn't make it "open-ended" .